# How to safely delete all Option Base 1 statements from a VBA project

Tags: excel, vba

I'm refactoring a VBA project with about 100 modules. Some of the modules are `Option Base 1`, others `Option Base 0` (the default). I'd like all modules to be `Option Base 0` as that simplifies moving functions between modules so that they are more sensibly located.

I think I'm safe to delete all `Option Base 1` statements in the project if:

1. All `Dim` and `ReDim` statements that set the dimensionality of arrays have explicit lower bounds.
2. I pay close attention to the use of the `Array()` function since this will return an array with lower bound determined by the `Option Base` of the module it's in.

Is there anything else I need to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

#### Option Base does not affect row counting

Note that `Option Base` does not affect row counting and therefore does not affect arrays that were filled out of range values like

```
Dim MyArr() As Variant
MyArr = Range("A1:A10").Value
```

will always result in an array `MyArr(1 To 10)` no matter if `Option Base` is `1` or `0`.

#### Watch out functions that return arrays

You might also need to watch out if a function returns an array that was created with `Array()` or with no explicit lower bounds. In that case you need also to check the parent functions/procedures array handling which might not be that obvious.

This is especialy tricky if different `Option Base` were used in different modules.

```
Option Base 1 'if you plan to change this to 0 

Function MyArrayReturningFunction() As Variant
    MyArrayReturningFunction = Array(1, 2, 3)
End Function


'in another module

Option Base 0 'this was already 0 
              'so you might assume no changes are needed in this module BUT WRONG!

Sub ParentProcedure()
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    MyArr = MyArrayReturningFunction

    Dim iItem As Long
    For iItem = 1 To 3 'You need to take care here even if this module was already Base 0 
                       'because the array was recieved from a Base 1 function.
                       'Especially in combination with cells (see next paragraph)
        Debug.Print MyArr(iItem)
    Next iItem
End Sub
```

#### Array numbering vs. row numbering

Also if loops were used for array looping **in combination** with cells and ranges you need to take special attention to the counters.

```
Option Base 1

Sub Test()
    Dim MyArr() As Variant
    MyArr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 'MyArr(1 To 5)

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr) 'It looks like safe to change because 
                                              'LBound/UBound is used BUT see below …
        Cells(iRow, A) = MyArr(iRow)
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Needs to change to

```
Option Base 0

Sub Test()
    Dim MyArr() As Variant
    MyArr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 'MyArr(0 To 4)

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr) 'even if LBound/UBound is already used,
        Cells(iRow + 1, A) = MyArr(iRow)      'the counter for the cells needs to be changed,
                                              'but NOT for the MyArr
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

#### Conclusion

In general I would consider that approach as safe but you will need to have a **decent** look into your code. There might be traps that are not obvious to see.

Answer (score 0):

All that PEH writes is correct, particularly that making this kind of change requires careful analysis.

This is the current state of my knowledge:

Code sensitive to changing the `Option Base` statement at the top of the module:

- `Dim MyArr(3)` lower bound set by `Option Base`.
- `ReDim MyArr(5)`lower bound set by `Option Base`.
- `Private MyArr(3)` lower bound set by `Option Base`.
- `Public MyArr(3)` lower bound set by `Option Base`.
- `MyArr = Array(1,2,3)` Unless written as `VBA.Array` the `Array` function returns an array with lower bound set by `Option Base` of the module.

Code not sensitive to changing `Option Base`:

- `Dim MyArr(1 To 3)` lower bound is 1.
- `ReDim MyArr(0 To 5)` lower bound is 0.
- `Private MyArr(0 To 5)` lower bound is 0.
- `Public MyArr(0 To 5)` lower bound is 0.
- `MyArr = VBA.Array(1,2,3)` lower bound is 0.
- `MyArr = Split("1,2,3",",")` lower bound is 0.
- `MyArr = VBA.Split("1,2,3",",")` lower bound is 0. So unlike `Array`, `Split`'s behaviour is the same whether or not prefixed by `VBA.`. It always returns an array with lower bound zero.

The following statements are true whatever the `Option Base` of a module:

- Indexing into a `Range.Cells` collection starts from 1.
- The `.Value` and `.Value2` property of a `Range` (with more than one cell) is a two-dimensional `Variant()` array whose lower bounds are 1.

I don't think that there are other "gotchas" to worry about, but I would like to know if there are.

Comment: To add: `Option Base` has no influence on [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/paramarray-must-be-declared-as-an-array-of-variant) which always starts at `0`. • The rest looks good.